# No module named "testing" when using testing.mysqld

Tags: python, python-module

`testing.mysqld` is the model for testing flask_mysqldb in the unit test

But I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'` After installing the module and use it.

Code in my script:

```
import unittest
import testing.mysqld

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.mysqld = testing.mysqld.Mysqld(my_cnf={'skip-networking': None})
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mysqld.stop()
```

I use mysql8 and MacOS, pip installed successfully, and MySQL already exists in my PATH

Comment: Are you importing the module in your script?

Comment: Yes, and it fail to import the module

Comment: Did you use easy_install or pip? Also is the MySQL Server in your path? as per these docs https://pypi.org/project/testing.mysqld/

Comment: try:
`from flask_mysqldb import testing.mysqld`

Comment: I used pip to install. And the MySQL Server already exists in my path

Comment: Sadly, the command does not work. I also tried from ```from flask_mysqldb.testing import mysqld```

Comment: What is the full name of your file that you made ? In the docs they had a file named testing.mysqld.Mysqld so just making sure it maches